# How can I extract matched part of multiple strings?

Tags: r, string

I have multiple strings, and I want to extract the part that matches.
In practice my strings are directories, and I need to choose where to write a file, which is the location that matches in all strings. For example, if you have a vector with three strings:

```
data.dir <- c("C:\\data\\files\\subset1\\", "C:\\data\\files\\subset3\\", "C:\\data\\files\\subset3\\")
```

...the part that matches in all strings is "C:\data\files\". How can I extract this?

Comment: Are you looking for an arbitrary match in the middle of the strings or are you just looking for a prefix match? If the latter, are you looking for a delimited match? (The application as presented does permit that last assumption, although the title doesn't suggest that limitation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strsplit` and `intersect` the overlapping parts recursively using `Reduce`. You can then piece it back together by `paste`-ing.

```
paste(Reduce(intersect, strsplit(data.dir, "\\\\")), collapse="\\")
#[1] "C:\\data\\files"
```

As @g-grothendieck notes, this will fail in certain circumstances like:

```
data.dir <- c("C:\\a\\b\\c\\", "C:\\a\\X\\c\\")
```

An ugly hack might be something like:

```
tail(
  Reduce(
    intersect,
    lapply(strsplit(data.dir, "\\\\"),
      function(x) sapply(1:length(x), function(y) paste(x[1:y], collapse="\\") ) 
    )
  ),
1)
```

...which will deal with either case.

---

Alternatively, use `dirname` if you only ever have one extra directory level:

```
unique(dirname(data.dir))
#[1] "C:/data/files"
```

Answer (score 2):

`g` contains the character positions to successive backslashes in `data.dir[1]`.  From this create a logical vector `ok` whose ith element is `TRUE` if the first `g[i]` characters of all elements in `data.dir` are the same, i.e. all elements of `substr(data.dir, 1, g[i])` are the same.    If `ok[1]` is `TRUE` then there is a non-zero length common prefix whose length is given by the first `g[k]` characters of `data.dir[1]` where `k` (which equals `rle(ok)$lengths[1]`) is the leading number of `TRUE` values in `ok`; otherwise, there is no common prefix so return `""`.

```
g <- gregexpr("\\", data.dir[1], fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
ok <- sapply(g, function(i) all(substr(data.dir[1], 1, i) == substr(data.dir, 1, i)))
if (ok[1]) substr(data.dir[1], 1, g[rle(ok)$lengths[1]]) else ""
```

For `data.dir` defined in the question the last line gives:

```
[1] "C:\\data\\files\\"
```